# link URL is not properly formatted thrown in

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am going to post a link using `PHP SDK`. I am using the following code to post the link

```
$data = $this->facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post',
                array(
            'message'=>'Hello',
            'link' => 'https://localhost/Sweepstack/publishedtab.php?ref=15',
            'access_token' => $this->access_token
                )
            );
```

But When I am trying to post this, I am getting error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) link URL is not properly formatted thrown in E:\wamp\www\Sweepstack\facebookClass\facebook-sdk\base_facebook.php on line 1271
```

How can I resolve this error, Please help me

Comment: Could it be that Facebook is not allowing you to post a link to a location it knows is inaccessible? You're trying to post a link to `https://localhost`. Can you try to post a link to a publicly accessible URL?

Comment: If I want to post with localhost, how can I

Comment: Lets first determine if that is the actual problem. There are ways around posting a local URL.

Comment: Yep I am able to post https://google.com

Comment: Why do you want a link to localhost?

Comment: just for testing purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. So [it does looks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568548/link-url-is-not-properly-formatted-thrown-in#comment27320730_18568548) like Facebook is blocking links to `localhost`.

What you'll want to do to circumvent this limitation is to create an entry in your hosts file with a dummy hostname pointing back to `127.0.0.1`. Something like:

```
fakelocalhost.com 127.0.0.1
```

Then just replace your URL with this fake hostname:

```
'link' => 'https://fakelocalhost.com/Sweepstack/publishedtab.php?ref=15'
```

Comment: Nice workaround.  It should be emphasized this fakelocalhost.com link will only work for testing on a machine on which the hosts file is changed.  I suppose that goes without saying, but for someone who is new to dev work and doesn't understand what's going on behind the scenes, this might throw them off.